# Is Component waiting for a promise from Redux Action Creator Anti-Pattern?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In some articles, some people are saying that UI states such as `isLoading` (Component Level), `isSubmitting`, `isFetching`, etc... shouldn't be in the Global State Store.  They should be kept and maintained in the Component State.

So, I tried to find out how to handle these kinds of states locally in the components.  I found out that we can use promises or async/await to handle (Ref: [Using Async/Await](https://medium.com/@nickcantelmi/from-the-name-of-submituserinformation-i-assumed-this-makes-a-request-to-a-server-bed85fefd890))

For example, this is how we can use `Promises` and `Redux-thunk` to handle `isSubmitting`

In Actions Creator:

```
export const addStudent = (payload) => {
    return function (dispatch) {        
        return StudentService.add(payload).then(() => {
            dispatch(addStudentSuccess());
            dispatch(fetchStudents());
        });
    };
}
```

In Redux Connected Component, wait for the completion and toggle the `isSubmitting` state:

```
async onSubmit={(values) => { 
   setState({isSubmitting: true});
   await this.props.addStudent(values); 
   setState({isSubmitting: false});
}}
```

However, on Redux page, it mentions that Redux is **a strict unidirectional data flow**.  It seems to me that Components waiting for the response back from the Action-Creators is breaking the unidirectional flow.  It becomes bi-directional flow as the following diagram (See the red arrow):

[image]

I would like to know whether it's allowed or good practice to do that.  Or I misunderstood about the Unidirectional data flow statement?

Answer (score 2):

Redux does have a unidirectional data flow but to use async/await or promises in your component's local state to handle UI states such as isLoading, isSubmitting, isFetching, etc is perfectly fine.

Local state should only be used for UI-related states though and not for business logic or data management.

So, for you it's fine. i.e. it is allowed and it is good practice to use async/await or promises in your component's local state.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that you should not set `isLoading` in project store.

Common approach is to use useState:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

async onSubmit={(values) => { 
   setIsLoading(true);
   await this.props.addStudent(values); 
   setIsLoading({false);
}}
```

And its ok to await from action, while you do not get **data** there, because redux is **one directional data flow**. So its ok to await async logic to run sync logic.

And as advanced approach you can use react 18 [useTransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition)
for cases such as `isLoading` or `isPending`.

example from docs:

```
function App() {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  function handleClick() {
    startTransition(() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isPending && <Spinner />}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

as you can see, we do not use `setIsLoading` manually, we just run code inside `startTransition`.

And minor tip about your code: it looks not good, that `addStudent` is passed through props, you can just import it. You should use props for that is changing in component lifecicle.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case.

Usually (or in good practice) put these state like `fetching/loading/refreshing` in current component instead of Redux store, but if you want to share the state across components, then put in store, eg: a global loading state.